# Book about a girl who notices a strange boy in her class and follows him to a cave

Tags: story-identification

This book is older, 80s maybe. I can’t remember character names but I remember the plot mostly. The main girl notices a strange boy in class. He’s very pale and has dark hair.

She follows him home one snowy day and sees him go into a cave. She falls going in and he’s angry she followed him but saves her. She becomes attached to him, distancing herself from her boyfriend, friends, choir, etc.  They watch her dance with no one (but it’s the boy) over a frozen lake and she falls in.

The cover was dark purple with maybe silver writing.

Comment: What about this was fantasy or sci-fi?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are there any fantasy elements in this story?  If there aren't it would be off-topic.  What happens to the girl after she falls in the lake?  Was this a novel or a manga?

Comment: I took the line "They watch her dance with no one (but it’s the boy)" to mean that the boy was really a ghost or otherwise invisible to all but the girl. Sounds SF, but definitely needs clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

*[The Stranger](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/308858)* by Caroline B. Cooney

[image: Front cover of The Stranger]

> From the first moment she sees him in class, Nicoletta is drawn to Jethro, fascinated by his dark, mysterious face. She is attracted yet repelled, interested but afraid. Nicoletta becomes obsessed, unable to think of anything but this strange boy.
>
> But she knows so little about him.
>
> Until she follows him to a deserted cave on the edge of town ... and learns the truth.
>
> Jethro is not like the others. No, not at all.
>
> He has a terrifying secret. A secret no one must ever find out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add some details of the plot to demonstrate how it matches the question?  A picture of a matching cover would help too.